# EdgeList of a graph reorders its vertex list

Tags: graphs-and-networks

As a simple example, consider this random graph:

```
rg = RandomGraph[{5, 8}];

EdgeList @ rg
```

> `{1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5}`

```
VertexList @ rg
```

> `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

Let's say we want to display the vertexes at some given points. We can write

```
Graph[rg, VertexCoordinates -> points]
```

If instead we write

```
Graph[Edgelist@rg, VertexCoordinates -> points]
```

we end up with the same graph, but a very different layout because its vertex List gets reordered as `{1, 3, 4, 5, 2}`.

Comment: Please always put the code in code blocks, not quotation blocks, and please formulate an explicit *question*.

Comment: You should always use `Graph[VertexList[rg], EdgeList[rg]]`.  What if it has some isolated vertices?

Comment: Ok thanks. Graph[VertexList[rg], EdgeList[rg]] keeps the order of vertexlist, nice!